# Indexing distinct values for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing a column `authors` that contains names of authors for different articles (different `rows`). I want to add a new column that contains a unique index for **every author**,i.e. let's say 12 for every occurrence of Dickens (just a random pick) in the `author` column.

Can it be done by a MySQL query or will I have to write a new script for doing this?

Comment: Add a column and execute a update query !\

Comment: I want to do it automatically for every author, not just a single author!

Comment: "A unique index for every author" - what does this mean?

Comment: `"12 for every occurrence of Dickens in the author column"` will it be a unique if it has more that one column with that same value.?

Comment: like I said, some value thats same for every occurrence of some author A but is not same for any different author B

Comment: @VishalSuthar I am interested only in the `author` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32cfe/1)

```
-- set up tables
create table Authors (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(64), 
  primary key(id)
  );

create table Books (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(64), 
  author varchar(64),
  primary key(id)
  );

-- populate Authors table, giving each author a unique ID
insert into  Authors (name)
select distinct author from Books;

-- Add an author_id column to the Books table
alter table Books add  author_id int(11) after author;

-- Update the Books table, filling in the author_ids
update Books b, Authors a
set b.author_id = a.id
where b.author = a.name;

-- If you don't care to retain the author name to author ID mapping,
-- you can then drop the Authors table.
```

Comment: That doesnt help :( .I want to add that column to `books` instead of a new table `authors` so that there exists an `authorid` for every entry of `name` in the table `books`.

Comment: @Arkanath, I don't understand. That's what `insert into  Authors (name) select distinct author from Books;  update Books b, Authors a
set b.author_id = a.id where b.author = a.name;` does  You can drop the Authors table after that if you want to.

Comment: Aah, sorry.. I didn't refresh the page to see your edit! It will work this way I think.